# How to get the dataset values to custom table in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

here i am trying to get the values retrieved from database to my custom table format. right now i am storing values to dataset.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String userID = Convert.ToString(Session["user_id"]);        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID) == true)
        {            
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }

        try { 
            string scon="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=bmtc;UID=root;";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(scon);
            String s = "select * from application";
            MySqlDataAdapter dat = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dat.Fill(ds,"tbl");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        catch(Exception ex){
           // Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Asp code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I need to save each individual values in table.
like

```
<table class="custom-table" id="preview-table">
<tr><td>Name</td><td><% value1 %></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address</td><td><% value2 %></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone</td><td><% value3 %></td></tr>
....
</table>
```

how can i do this?

Comment: i think you need to map the name in the grid with the dataset

Comment: `Gridview` control is anyways rendered as `html table`. If you want to show some custom controls consider using `Repeater` control instead.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check my answer?

Comment: @RahulSingh yes got it working. thank you.

Comment: @MithunRaikar - Okay that's great but why you have replaced it with `Listview`? As I mentioned your gridview was fine.

Comment: @RahulSingh  I am still using the grid view with same logic as listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listview`

```
<asp:ListView ID="listview1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table class="custom-table" id="preview-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Header1
            </th>
            <th>
                Header2
            </th>
            <th>
                Header3
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr><asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder></tr>            
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Column1") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Column2") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Column3") %>
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**At Server side code :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String userID = Convert.ToString(Session["user_id"]);        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID) == true)
        {            
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }

        try { 
            string scon="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=bmtc;UID=root;";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(scon);
            String s = "select * from application";
            MySqlDataAdapter dat = new MySqlDataAdapter(s, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dat.Fill(ds,"tbl");
            listview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            listview1.DataBind();
        }

        catch(Exception ex){
           // Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

For More information follow below links

[listView Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET), [listView Example 2](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-use-table-layout-in-ListView-control-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, an ASP.NET `Gridview` control is anyways rendered as Html table in browser, so their is no need to define a custom table separately. Now, as it stands by default the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of gridview is `true` so if you simply bind the data programatically (as you are doing now), it will render a table.

If you don't wish to display any specific column then either don't fetch it from DB or else set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and add BoundField for each column.

Although, there are some issues with your current code, first you should only be binding the data on initial get request i.e don't bind the data after every postback:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //code to get user_id
       If(!PostBack)
       {
           //code to bind gridview.
       }
  }
```

Apart from this, you should store the connection string in `Web.Config` file. You should consider using the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose expensive db related objects.